# How is undefined converted into binary in javascript?

Tags: javascript, binary, undefined, bitwise-operators

How is `undefined` treated in Binary in javascript?
It throws error when I do `(undefined).toString(2)`.

But when I do

```js
undefined & 0 //returns 0 
undefined & 1 //returns 0 
undefined | 0 //returns 0 
undefined | 1 //returns 1
```

One might guess that `undefined` might be converted into 0 . Or Is there any other thing going ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of. When bitwise operators (and other operators which only make sense in terms of math - such as `-` and `*` and `**` etc) are used, both expressions are converted [into numbers first](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator).

```
4. Let lnum be ? ToNumeric(lval).
5. Let rnum be ? ToNumeric(rval).
```

And [`ToNumeric`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumeric) [does `ToNumber`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber) which has

```
Argument Type   Result
Undefined       Return NaN.
```

And then the [binary operators call](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numberbitwiseop) [`ToInt32`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toint32) on each operator, which has

> 2. If number is NaN, +0, -0, +∞, or -∞, return +0.

So they're effectively converted into NaN in preparation for the mathematical operation, and then NaN gets converted to 0 for the binary operation.

`(undefined).toString(2)` doesn't work because accessing a property (like `toString`) of an expression only works if the expression is an object, or a primitive that can be wrapped in an object. Undefined and null are not objects, nor can they be converted into one, so trying to access any property of them throws.